# given a date object in python, how do I subtract one day

Tags: python

have a variable I've set up

`now = datetime.datetime.now()`

I want to be able to set up a variable, `yesterday`, that just takes `now` and subtracts one day from it.

I'm sure that this is super-easy, but how do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date

Answer (score 7):

You can use `datetime.timedelta`:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
yesterday = now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```