# How to subtract a day from datetime format in python?

Tags: python, datetime, subtraction

I'm trying print the day ranges from today up to a year ago. So i can apply this to a sql query in my other code.
I know my algorithm works but i need to subtract 1 day from the format '2014-05-15'
Here is the code

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime
current_date = datetime.date.today()
datecounter = 0
while datecounter != 365:
    print current_date
    date_start = current_date
    print date_start
    # current_date = current_date.timedelta(days=1)
    print current_date
    print 'the date is between', date_start, 'and', current_date
    datecounter += 1
```

im looking for this code to output

```
the date is between 2014-05-16 and 2014-05-15
the date is between 2014-05-15 and 2014-04-14
```

etc

i wrote a contrived example based on the logic, if you would like to run it yourself, you may better understand what i am trying to do.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
curdate = 5
for i in x:
    print curdate
    date_start = curdate
    curdate = curdate - 1
    # print curdate


    print ' the date is between', date_start, 'and', curdate
    print ' ---------- '
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
curdate=curdate-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date)

**Edit**

Your code could also do with some cleaning:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

cur_date = date.today()
for i in xrange(365):
    start_date, cur_date = cur_date, cur_date-timedelta(days=1)
    print "the date is between {} and {}".format(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), cur_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

This will output exactly what you want.

Comment: i have that in my code commented out

Comment: You have a line commented out in your code, however you are setting current_date equal to the timedelta.  you need to make sure you are actually subtracting.

Comment: As @lafferjm said, the commented line is the problem; as it isn't actually doing what you think it is doing

Comment: sorry for duplicate post

Comment: thanks mike actually going to use that