# How to find the date n days ago in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime, timedelta

I would like to write a script where I give Python a number of days (let's call it `d`) and it gives me the date we were `d` days ago.

I am struggling with the module datetime:

```
import datetime 

tod = datetime.datetime.now()
d = timedelta(days = 50) 
a = tod - h 
Type Error : unsupported operand type for - : "datetime.timedelta" and 
"datetime.datetime"
```

Comment: What is `h` supposed to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I subtract a day from a python date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date)

Answer (score 114):

You have mixed something up with your variables, you can subtract timedelta `d` from `datetime.datetime.now()` with no issue:

```
import datetime 
tod = datetime.datetime.now()
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 50)
a = tod - d
print(a)
2014-12-13 22:45:01.743172
```

Comment: you can also format the date with the method strftime(), e.g. get it in local date format, get just date (without time), etc.etc. At print write

print(strftime( %x)) 

for local vesrion of date.

All the legal formats here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp

Answer (score 36):

Below code should work

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

N_DAYS_AGO = 5

today = datetime.now()    
n_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=N_DAYS_AGO)
print today, n_days_ago
```

Answer (score 11):

If your arguments are something like, yesterday,2 days ago, 3 months ago, 2 years ago. The function below could be of help in getting the exact date for the arguments.
You first need to import the following date utils

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

Then implement the function below

```
def get_past_date(str_days_ago):
    TODAY = datetime.date.today()
    splitted = str_days_ago.split()
    if len(splitted) == 1 and splitted[0].lower() == 'today':
        return str(TODAY.isoformat())
    elif len(splitted) == 1 and splitted[0].lower() == 'yesterday':
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(days=1)
        return str(date.isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['hour', 'hours', 'hr', 'hrs', 'h']:
        date = datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(hours=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.date().isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['day', 'days', 'd']:
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(days=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['wk', 'wks', 'week', 'weeks', 'w']:
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(weeks=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['mon', 'mons', 'month', 'months', 'm']:
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(months=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.isoformat())
    elif splitted[1].lower() in ['yrs', 'yr', 'years', 'year', 'y']:
        date = TODAY - relativedelta(years=int(splitted[0]))
        return str(date.isoformat())
    else:
        return "Wrong Argument format"
```

You can then call the function like this:

```
print get_past_date('5 hours ago')
print get_past_date('yesterday')
print get_past_date('3 days ago')
print get_past_date('4 months ago')
print get_past_date('2 years ago')
print get_past_date('today')
```

Comment: Actually Im looking for the inverse (datetime to "Time Difference") but, Im gonna keep this, its cool! Take my like bro!

Answer (score 11):

we can get the same as like this ,It is applicable for past and future dates also.

Current Date:

```
import datetime
Current_Date = datetime.datetime.today()
print (Current_Date)
```

Previous Date:

```
import datetime
Previous_Date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1) #n=1
print (Previous_Date)
```

Next-Day Date:

```
import datetime
NextDay_Date = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print (NextDay_Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the applications where you want to provide user convenient input format of relative dates you might look at parser from [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) Python package. It is a solution along the lines proposed by [Simeon Babatunde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139601/3247880) but more capable. The usage is as:

```py
from dateparser import parse

date_time = parse('10 days ago')
``
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime,timedelta   
past = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=50)
print(past.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem, make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond existing answers, the relevant advantage which your solution achieves, especially if the difference is so small and non-obvious, in order to avoid the impression of only copying existing solutions to questionably trawl for reputation. Consider taking the [tour].