How to download/use multiple CSV files from a website in python
I have been trying to download the Day ahead Market ExPost LMPs csv files from this website:
https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/real-time--market-data/market-reports#nt=/MarketReportType:Historical%20LMP/MarketReportName:Day-Ahead%20Market%20ExPost%20LMPs%20(csv)
I need the information from the various columns and rows within the Excel files for later use in my project. As a result, I have begun this process by writing this snippet of code. However, I am getting several error messages, and as I am still learning Python, I am unsure of how to tackle these errors. I am also trying to stay away from using ChatGPT so I can effectively learn, and that is why I am asking here. Any help would be appreciated; thanks.
Here is the snippet of code I have written in Jupyter Labs:
import urllib3
import pandas as pd
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
url = 'https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/real-time--market-data/market-reports#nt=/MarketReportType:Historical%20LMP/MarketReportName:Day-Ahead%20Market%20ExPost%20LMPs%20(csv)'
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/real-time--market-data/market-reports#nt=/MarketReportType:Historical%20LMP/MarketReportName:Day-Ahead%20Market%20ExPost%20LMPs%20(csv)', skiprows = 5)
df.head() 

Here are the error messages I am receiving:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File /lib/python311.zip/urllib/request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1347 try:
-> 1348     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1349               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error

File /lib/python311.zip/http/client.py:1283, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1282 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1283 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File /lib/python311.zip/http/client.py:1329, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1328     body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1329 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /lib/python311.zip/http/client.py:1278, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1277     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1278 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /lib/python311.zip/http/client.py:1038, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1037 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1038 self.send(msg)
   1040 if message_body is not None:
   1041 
   1042     # create a consistent interface to message_body

File /lib/python311.zip/http/client.py:976, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
    975 if self.auto_open:
--> 976     self.connect()
    977 else:

File /lib/python311.zip/http/client.py:1448, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
   1446 "Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port."
-> 1448 super().connect()
   1450 if self._tunnel_host:

File /lib/python311.zip/http/client.py:942, in HTTPConnection.connect(self)
    941 sys.audit("http.client.connect", self, self.host, self.port)
--> 942 self.sock = self._create_connection(
    943     (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    944 # Might fail in OSs that don't implement TCP_NODELAY

File /lib/python311.zip/socket.py:851, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, all_errors)
    850 if not all_errors:
--> 851     raise exceptions[0]
    852 raise ExceptionGroup("create_connection failed", exceptions)

File /lib/python311.zip/socket.py:836, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, all_errors)
    835     sock.bind(source_address)
--> 836 sock.connect(sa)
    837 # Break explicitly a reference cycle

OSError: [Errno 23] Host is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 5
      3 urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
      4 url = 'https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/real-time--market-data/market-reports#nt=/MarketReportType:Historical%20LMP/MarketReportName:Day-Ahead%20Market%20ExPost%20LMPs%20(csv)'
----> 5 df = pd.read_csv('https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/real-time--market-data/market-reports#nt=/MarketReportType:Historical%20LMP/MarketReportName:Day-Ahead%20Market%20ExPost%20LMPs%20(csv)', skiprows = 5)
      6 df.head() 

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:950, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    935 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    936     dialect,
    937     delimiter,
   (...)
    946     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    947 )
    948 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 950 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:605, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    602 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    604 # Create the parser.
--> 605 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    607 if chunksize or iterator:
    608     return parser

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1442, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
   1439     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
   1441 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
-> 1442 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1735, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1733     if "b" not in mode:
   1734         mode += "b"
-> 1735 self.handles = get_handle(
   1736     f,
   1737     mode,
   1738     encoding=self.options.get("encoding", None),
   1739     compression=self.options.get("compression", None),
   1740     memory_map=self.options.get("memory_map", False),
   1741     is_text=is_text,
   1742     errors=self.options.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
   1743     storage_options=self.options.get("storage_options", None),
   1744 )
   1745 assert self.handles is not None
   1746 f = self.handles.handle

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:713, in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    710     codecs.lookup_error(errors)
    712 # open URLs
--> 713 ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
    714     path_or_buf,
    715     encoding=encoding,
    716     compression=compression,
    717     mode=mode,
    718     storage_options=storage_options,
    719 )
    721 handle = ioargs.filepath_or_buffer
    722 handles: list[BaseBuffer]

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:363, in _get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    361 # assuming storage_options is to be interpreted as headers
    362 req_info = urllib.request.Request(filepath_or_buffer, headers=storage_options)
--> 363 with urlopen(req_info) as req:
    364     content_encoding = req.headers.get("Content-Encoding", None)
    365     if content_encoding == "gzip":
    366         # Override compression based on Content-Encoding header

File /lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:265, in urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    259 """
    260 Lazy-import wrapper for stdlib urlopen, as that imports a big chunk of
    261 the stdlib.
    262 """
    263 import urllib.request
--> 265 return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)

File /lib/python311.zip/urllib/request.py:216, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    214 else:
    215     opener = _opener
--> 216 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File /lib/python311.zip/urllib/request.py:519, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    516     req = meth(req)
    518 sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
--> 519 response = self._open(req, data)
    521 # post-process response
    522 meth_name = protocol+"_response"

File /lib/python311.zip/urllib/request.py:536, in OpenerDirector._open(self, req, data)
    533     return result
    535 protocol = req.type
--> 536 result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    537                           '_open', req)
    538 if result:
    539     return result

File /lib/python311.zip/urllib/request.py:496, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    494 for handler in handlers:
    495     func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 496     result = func(*args)
    497     if result is not None:
    498         return result

File /lib/python311.zip/urllib/request.py:1391, in HTTPSHandler.https_open(self, req)
   1390 def https_open(self, req):
-> 1391     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
   1392         context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)

File /lib/python311.zip/urllib/request.py:1351, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1348         h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1349                   encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1350     except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1351         raise URLError(err)
   1352     r = h.getresponse()
   1353 except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 23] Host is unreachable>

Despite trying various fixes, I have yet to find a solution. I have referred to many of the other solutions on this website too, however those do not seem to work for my case either it seems. Any tips/help would be appreciated.

You are pointing pd.read_csv at an HTML page. You need to point it at the actual .csv data that you get. There's a lot of .csv files there. Do you need all 875?

Thanks for the reply. Yes, I need all 875 pages.  That's the reason why I tried using the URL to the actual website for that specific subsection of files. If it were just the one file, I would've just used its csv link. That's why I'm confused about how to write code to download all those files.

If they follow a pattern, such as they are today and each day before then you modify your code to generate each and every file name and download them. To do that you'll need Python's datatime module. This should help you. It gets the data for a number of days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268868/8508004 . Code like that and how to format it are what you seek to flesh this out. For formatting the information into the string of the URL, you'll need to use strftime. Work on the code to get your code to make the strings first before you...

Alright, thank you. I'm going to attempt this.

 try to connect it to trying to download all the CSVs. Breaking the problem down like that will save you from trying things before you are ready. With communication on the internet you don't want to slam a site either. So that's another reason to hold off until you know you code is working. Plus, you want to built in a pause using time.sleep() to getting each CSV in other to not overtax the server and stand the chance of getting blocked as making too many requests too quickly. Try 3 seconds in between requests? Maybe only get the first 5 files until you know it works. Then up it.

Two things here:

The url variable is unused
The string argument (the url that should point to the csv) on line 5 points to an html page with links to different csvs, but not the csvs themselves.

So, with those things in mind, the below code should work. Notice, the url is now arbitrarily the first csv linked at the url you originally used:
import urllib3
import pandas as pd
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
df = pd.read_csv('https://docs.misoenergy.org/marketreports/20240524_da_expost_lmp.csv', skiprows = 5)
df.head() 

Now, regarding getting all 875 of these csv files, luckily for you, all of them are predictably named: date_da_expost_lmp.csv, with the oldest file being 20220101_da_expost_lmp.csv and the latest being 20240524_da_expost_lmp.csv. This is useful, because, rather than writing code to scrape all of those filenames from all 88 pages, you could write a list comprehension to generate all of the URLs for you, like this:
urls = [
    f"https://docs.misoenergy.org/marketreports/{d.strftime('%Y%m%d')}_da_expost_lmp.csv" for d in pandas.date_range('20220101', '20240524')
]
for url in urls:
    df = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows = 5)
    time.sleep(3)
    # Todo: do something with df...


Thanks for the reply. I understand that the URL you provided works. However, I need to write code that can download all 875 pages of Excel files on that website for that section.

I'm updating the answer to give some clarity to you on that part as we speak
