# Building correct MySQL datetime formatted string for yesterday in Python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have tried something like this:

```
datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',(datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24))
```

I just want to get a MySQL formatted string for yesterday. The above is not working as `strftime` expects a `datetime.date` and I gave a string.

Comment: `(dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=24)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @bernie surprised that works! I considered that but didn't think that would actually work. Thanks!

Comment: @bernie feel free to submit an answer, this did solve it. However, I removed the `dt.` parts.

Comment: Beware timezone issues: [How can I subtract a day from a python date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441147/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want instead:

```
(datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```