# yesterdays date and time showing single digit day - python

Tags: python, time, strftime

Hi my following code provides me with a single digit day(e.g 2015_09_1) even though I'm after 2 digits for yesterdays day:

```
import time 

yesterday = time.strftime("%Y_%m_") + str(int(time.strftime('%d'))-1)
print(yesterday)
```

Comment: Why are you going through an int and back to string?  If you want two digits, just put the `%d` on the end of the `%Y_%m_` string.

Comment: @MarkReed then it's not 'yesterday', note the -1

Comment: This is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first, even if you solved the zero-padding problem, that's not going to work.  Today it will say that yesterday was September 0th.  On January 1st it will get the year wrong, too.

Just subtract a day (86,400 seconds) from the current time and *then* format as a string.

```
yesterday = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d", time.localtime(time.time()-86400))
```

If you prefer not to muck around with seconds-based arithmetic, see @taesu's answer using `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: thank you! much appreciated!

Comment: it may produce a wrong date around DST transitions. [There is a difference between "same time a day ago" and "24 hours ago"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427822/4279). Note: @taesu's answer works even around DST transitions (except for (rare) cases when the corresponding date does not exist in the local timezone).

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
d = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
print d.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
```

there's nothing wrong with using `time`,
however I personally prefer `datetime`, just because it's cleaner.

one reason why I would use this approach is because what if I want to get the day before yesterday, then I would have to `86,400*2`.

with `timedelta`, it's simply `days=2`

Comment: thank you! much appreciated!

Comment: [there *is* something wrong with the `time`-based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340618/yesterdays-date-and-time-showing-single-digit-day-python?noredirect=1#comment52590622_32340715)

Comment: thank you. did not know about that.