# Why datetime.fromtimestamp adds additional hour?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, calendar

I've found, that `datetime.fromtimestamp` adds additional hour in some circumstances.

No additional hour:

```
In [1]: import datetime as dt

In [2]: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(946674000 + (85*60*60*24))
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 26, 0, 0)
```

Notice - additional hour:

```
In [3]: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(946674000 + (86*60*60*24))
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 27, 1, 0)
```

But if use `datetime.timedelta` - no additional hour:

```
In [4]: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(946674000) + dt.timedelta(seconds=86*60*60*24)
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 27, 0, 0)
```

How that could be explained?

Comment: the local timezone may have different utc offset at different times.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Why `timedelta` works differently then?

Comment: timedelta is "dumb". It doesn't take into account your local timezone. See [How can I subtract a day from a Python date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441147/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But doesn't `fromtimestamp()` operates in UTC, which has no DST?

Comment: fromtimestamp() returns *local* time that may observe DST.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Indeed.