# how to determine the date now knowing how many days have passed since a given date

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
df = pd.read_csv(dataname, sep=',')

# get rid of the format issue
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Date' }, inplace=True)

# select desired columns
df = df[['Date', 'Close']]

# define your format in the Date column
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'

#initialize an empty string
numdays=['ha']    #need to add a column title

# select the first date
date1 = datetime.strptime(df['Date'][len(df['Date'])-1], date_format)

for i in range(0,len(df['Date'])):
# select the second date
    date2 = datetime.strptime(df['Date'][i], date_format)

    # calculate the difference between the dates
    diffDates = date2 - date1

    numdays.append(diffDates.days)   #numb of days between two given dates 


# calculate the difference between the dates
diffDates = date2 - date1
```

Above is what i have to determine the number of days between two given dates.

Now, I'd like to do the opposite.

Suppose you know how many days have passed since 1/03/2008 for example,

Is there a simple way in Python to find out what month/day/year it is now? given the number of days between 1/03/2008 and now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

YOUR_DATE = date.today() - timedelta(days=NUMBER_OF_DAYS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `date` class from the `datetime`module.  To get the current date, use `.today()`method.

An easy way to count days is to subtract the ordinal values.  Another way is to use `timedelta` class.

```
from datetime import date
d1 = date( 2008, 3, 1 )    # Y,M,D 
d2 = date.today()
diff_days_v1 = d2.toordinal() - d1.toordinal()
diff_days_v2 = ( d2 - d1 ).days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

YOUR_DATE = date(2008, 03, 01) + timedelta(days=NUMBER_OF_DAYS)
```

[Also check Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

I am Considering you want to find now date just by passing total no of days from given date to now date

Try this,

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
old_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2008-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
t = datetime.datetime.now() - old_date
now_date = old_date + timedelta(days=t.days)
now_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(now_date, '%m/%d/%Y') # As you want format like month/date/year
print now_date
```