# Get difference in days between today's date and previous date

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using the "datetime" module and I'm trying to work out the difference between two dates in **days**. Here's the code that I'm using, with some other code coming before it that gets the object `sub.created_utc` (a POSIX timestamp, or unix timestap):

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(sub.created_utc);
print(sub.created_utc);
print(date);
print(datetime.datetime.now() - date);
```

and here is the output:

```
1440736746.0
2015-08-28 04:39:06
287 days, 16:47:41.560711
```

My question is, how do I get the `287 days` part of that (or just `287`, I don't mind either way). I know I could use regex to just extract that part of it, but is there a better more reliable way of doing it?

Thanks for any help! If you want me to give the full code I can provide it, just wouldn't think it would be necessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you subtract the dates, you get a `datetime.timedelta` object, and you can access its properties directly:

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(sub.created_utc)
print(sub.created_utc)
print(d1)
result = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - d1
print(result.days)
```

Python statements don't end in `;`; and `date` is the name of a built-in library; so best not to use it in your code.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also the semicolons are a habit, coming for JS and PHP development. Doesn't seem to bring up errors or slow programs down so how bad is it?

Comment: @MatthewMob: unrelated: you should use `utcnow()`, not `now()` here.

Answer (score 1):

the statement

```
datetime.datetime.now() - date
```

yields a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object. It has attributes like `days` or `seconds` etc.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

The datetime module in Python has got a function called timedelta. Delta in MATHS and in GREEK means difference. For example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
delta = b-a
```

so for answering to your question you have to write:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
d = date.today() - timedelta(days=delta_days)
```

where delta_days are the days that you have to subtract.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to `datetime`, you could get the current Unix time using `time.time()`. It allows to find the time difference in days given a Unix time from the past:

```
import time

DAY = 86400 # POSIX day - the exact value
days_ago = (time.time() - sub.created_utc) // DAY
```