# If time is more and less then one day in django app

Tags: python, django, time, django-template-filters

I have django app and problems with set correct conditions for dates:

1. I want to check if it's more than 24 hours (1 day) before event - show days
2. I want to check if it's less than 24 hours (1 day) before event - show hours and minutes
3. Check if event is between date_from and date_to

Here are my filters:

Task 1

```
@register.filter(name='if_more_then_24')
def if_more_then_24(time):
    return time + datetime.timedelta(hours=24) > timezone.now()
```

Task 2

```
@register.filter(name='if_less_then_24')
def if_less_then_24(time):
    return time + datetime.timedelta(hours=24) < timezone.now()
```

Task 3

```
@register.filter(name='now_online')
def now_online(time):
    return time < timezone.now()


@register.filter(name='not_online')
def not_online(time):
    return time > timezone.now()
```

But code didn't work because when I have 
{{ object.event_from }} Dec. 11, 2016, 5:00 p.m.
and today is Dec. 12, 2016, 4:31 p.m.
Counter shows hours 1:28 instead days

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "doesn't work", are you getting an error message?

Comment: @will please check my update

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have your logic backward:

```
def if_more_then_24(time):
    return time + datetime.timedelta(hours=24) > timezone.now()
```

If a given `time` (say sometime yesterday) + 24 hours is *greater than* right now, that means that it was less then 24 hours ago (because adding 24 hours results in a time in the future).

```
def if_less_then_24(time):
    return time + datetime.timedelta(hours=24) < timezone.now()
```

If a given `time` + 24 hours is less than right now, it means that `time` was more than 24 hours ago, because adding a day still is in the past.

So, wherever you're calling your functions will be expecting the opposite result.  Switch the `<` and `>` in these functions, and it should correct this.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-can-i-subtract-a-day-from-a-python-date) for more on subtracting one day.