# First available date previous day/month/year from a datetime range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a datetime instance with dates (`dfDates`):

```
2017-03-01 00:00
2017-03-02 00:00
2017-03-04 00:00
...
```

For the last day (here: `2017-03-04`) I calculate the previous day/month/year/etc. as follows:

```
def previous_day(dtToday):
    return dtToday - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
```

This returns `2017-03-03`. However, this business day is not available in my range of dates (`dfDates`).

I am therefore looking for a robust way to find the date that is the closest to the previous day/month/year/etc.. In this case for the previous day it should return `2017-03-02`.

Note, I understand that you can do something like index `-1` to get the previous day. It becomes however complicated when taking the previous month (there are not always `30` days in a month) and even the previous year (there are not always `252` working days in a year). Is there therefore a robust method to get the closest available date?

**Update**

I understand also that you can use timedelta as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
```

However, how does that relate to `dtToday` and how can I link it with `dfDates`? `dtToday` in my case is not always `datetime.today()`. Sometimes its a random date.

Comment: I am not seeing how it works exactly. `d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)` but where in that is my dtToday and how does it link to `dfDates`. I am using a specific date `dtToday` which is not always `datetime.today()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

- `dtToday` = the reference date
- `dtDates` = a datetime sequence of the
  available dates
- `nbOffset` = the number of days/months/years we want
  to go back

Code:

```
def previous_day(dtToday, dtDates, nbOffset):
    prevx   = dtToday - pd.DateOffset(days=nbOffset)
    return test_day_in(prevx, dtDates)

def previous_month(dtToday, dtDates, nbOffset):
    prevx = dtToday - pd.DateOffset(months=nbOffset)
    return test_day_in(prevx, dtDates)

def previous_year(dtToday, dtDates, nbOffset):
    prevx = dtToday - pd.DateOffset(years=nbOffset)
    return test_day_in(prevx, dtDates)

def test_day_in(dtTest, dtDates):
    if dtTest in dtDates:
        return dtTest
    else:
        return tryNextDay(dtTest, dtDates)

def tryNextDay(dtTest, dtDates):

    # if not outside the bound
    if (dtTest < dtDates.min()):
        return dtDates.min()

    # check if next day exist
    if (dtTest + pd.DateOffset(days=1) <= dtDates.max()):
        return previous_day(dtTest + pd.DateOffset(days=2), dtDates, 1) # 2-1
    else:
        print('warning, tryNextDay triggered')
        # should not be triggered, it should take by default the dtDates.min() if far outside range
        return dtTest
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient, but you can try:

```
# From your function
day_minus_one = previous_day(dtToday)

# Return LAST element in INDEX of DF FROM START TO DAY_MINUS_ONE
actual = df.loc[:day_minus_one].index[-1]
```

This essentially returns you the **last index** of a copy of your df, **up to and including day_minus_one, if any of the dates exist**. This should give you the closest date, or the date itself.

You can try:

```
# Returns LAST element of INDEX of df from DAY_MINUS_ONE_HUNDRED to DAY_MINUS_ONE
actual_better = df.loc[day_minus_one_hundred:day_minus_one].index[-1]
```

To only look back one_hundred days from minus_one if your dataset is huge, so you don't have to return a huge array just to find one date.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to actually subtract 1 day, you want to get the previous available day from the list of available dates. If that's the case, then consider this :

```
available_dates = [
  2017-03-01 00:00,
  2017-03-02 00:00,
  2017-03-04 00:00,
  ...
]

def previous_day(dtToday):
    today_index = available_dates.index(dtToday)
    return available_dates[today_index-1]
```

This assumes, of course, that your `available_dates` is sorted

EDIT:

If you want to be able to subtract month and years, then something a little bit more complex is needed :

```
# Sorted
available_dates = [
  2017-03-01 00:00,
  2017-03-02 00:00,
  2017-03-04 00:00,
  ...
]

subtract_from_date(date, day=None, month=None, year=None):
  # check if it's day/month/yeah
  ...
  # do the actual subtraction and store it in substracted_date
  ...
  # get the closest date
  for index, date in enumerate(available_dates):
     if date > substracted_date:
       return available_dates[index-1]
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine for minus 1 day (-1). But what about one month before? A month does not always have 30 days.