# How to add a day to make it equal with original datetime?

Tags: python, string, datetime, odoo, utc

I am importing a task from Office365 and while importing it, its `datetime` changes. For example if I set due date to 27-10-2019, when the task is imported, it results in 26-10-2019 with timezone UTC. I don't know why it is reducing one day.
Following its original date.[image]

Now it is upcoming date.
[image]

Any suggestion or help?

Comment: Make sure Office uses the same TZ, because it looks like it does not.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes; it is using the same time zone

Comment: Have you checked [this post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-date?rq=1)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski no, let me check it out...

Comment: Can you share the code of Odoo where the date(time) from Office365 is fetched and where it will be either written to or is creating a task/activity? Because one can only guess what is happening here, but nobody can answer the question with so less info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only because Odoo store the date time in UTC in database and converted it when you show it.

Exemple: Your date come from Office is 27-10-19 00:00:00 -2. When you save this date in odoo DB, if you doesn't convert it in UTC before. Odoo save the date like this 27-10-19 00:00:00 UTC. You lose your TZ.

And when you try to show it with the same TZ in Odoo. You will see 26-10-19 22:00:00