# How to Have Python Make a Variable with a Data Two Years Ago from Todays Date

Tags: python, date, time, python-datetime, python-dateutil

So I need to make a variable in python to have it send off today's date two years ago. I am having to automate a report in Salesforce using Selenium and need to have the form created by a send.keys() method from a variable.

[image]
The variable I have for today's date is :

```py
from datetime import date
import time
today = date.today()
current_date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

However, I need the past date to be that value printed from two years ago.

```py
from datetime import date
import time
today = date.today()
past_date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") - 2*(365)
```

However, I get this output:

```py
>>> past_date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") - 2*(365)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I presume it has something to with integer operations and string operations being in the same variable, thereby causing a string mismatch. Does anyone have a solution to help me get the date from two years ago in a dynamic way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-date

Comment: respectively do it with years or months

Comment: Thanks, it seems that worked. Awesome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to subtract a day from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-date)

Comment: @AMC it did answer my question in terms of subtracting from a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be done with standard library.

To specifically address your error, on this line you are turning the date into a string and then trying to subtract numbers from it.

```
past_date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") - 2*(365)
```

However to solve your issue we can change the code up a little:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
current_date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

try:
    past_date = today.replace(year=today.year-2) # the 2 on this line is how many years in the past you need.
except ValueError:
    past_date = today.replace(year=today.year-2, day=today.day-1)

print(past_date)
```

The try-except is to handle leap year issues.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Ευάγγελος Γρηγορόπουλος I was able to get the following to work based off his comments from [How to subtract a day from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-date)

I was able to use

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
past_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=730)
```

Comment: This is *mostly* correct. It doesn't give the exact day when counting for leap years. Like running this code right now will give March 19, 2018 because this year was a leap year.

Comment: That is true, will your code account for leap year?