# Django filter date before deadline

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to filter the date 5 days before the deadline in Django, I already have a query but not working. How can I solve this?

> **django views**

```
def bdeadline(request):
        def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        dl = books.objects.filter(deadline = datetime.now().date() +timedelta(days=5))
        return  render(request, 'deadline.html',{'title':'Car - Deadline', 'dl':'dl'})
```

Comment: I think you can find this in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-date)

Comment: What field type is `deadline`

Comment: deadline = models.DateTimeField()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential problems in your code. One is querying `DateTimeField` with date data. Another is sending string `dl` as context.

```
dl = books.objects.filter(deadline = datetime.now().date() +timedelta(days=5))
#                         ^^^^^^^^^ 
return  render(request, 'deadline.html',{'title':'Car - Deadline', 'dl':'dl'})
#                                                                       ^^^^
```

So, you can fix like this:

```
def bdeadline(request):
    dl = books.objects.filter(deadline__date = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=5))  # consider using PascalCase when naming classes(based on pep 8)
    return  render(request, 'deadline.html',{'title':'Car - Deadline', 'dl':dl})
```

I am using [**`__date`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#date) to get only the date data of the database.