# How to subtract a date string from a int in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to subtract a date string in python but get this error trap.

```
if intDay >= 28:
    m0weekbeg = str(wendMonth) + "/16/" + str(wendYear)
    weekBegDay = "16"
    weekEndDay = str(intDay)

dteStartDate = m0weekbeg
mstartdate = m0weekbeg 
mstopdate = m0weekend
cnt= 0
int(cnt)
dteStartDate =datetime.strptime(dteStartDate,'%m/%d/%Y')
startDay = str(dteStartDate.day)
while startDay != 2:
    cnt = cnt+1
    dteStartDate = m0weekbeg-cnt
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Python37-32\pr_import.py", line 242, in proceed
    dteStartDate = m0weekbeg-cnt
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: `m0weekbeg` is a string. You're trying to subtract a number from a string.

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite this foxpro program and I'm trying to subtract the day of the date.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [How to subtract a day from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441147/4518341)

Comment: @user13470314 FWIW you should [edit] the question to mention what you're trying to do and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m0weekbeg` is a string and you can't subtract int from str:

```
if intDay >= 28:
    m0weekbeg = datetime.date(wendYear, wendMonth, 16)#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    weekBegDay = "16"
    weekEndDay = str(intDay)

dteStartDate = m0weekbeg.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
mstartdate = m0weekbeg.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
mstopdate = m0weekend
cnt= 0
int(cnt)
dteStartDate =datetime.strptime(dteStartDate,'%m/%d/%Y')
startDay = str(dteStartDate.day)
while startDay != 2:
    cnt = cnt+1
    dteStartDate = m0weekbeg-datetime.timedelta(days=cnt)#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

but this code looks really awful. I think it would be a better idea to rewrite it instead of just translating it statement for statement.