# how to change the date if it is sunday or saturday in batch file

Tags: python, pandas

I have to a run a python script in command line and pass the date as argument and below is my command to run the date

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('date')
tdate= parser.parse_args().date
```

i would like to change this to check if it is sunday or saturday. If it is saturday, tdate should be tdate-1 and if it is sunday , it should be tdate-2.

I tried to get weekno in python and if it is 5, i am considering this as saturday and if it is 6 then it is sunday.

```
#this code is in python getting today() weekday()
weekno = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
if weekno==5:
    tdate= parser.parse_args().date-1
elif weekno==6:
    tdate= parser.parse_args().date-2
else:
    tdate= parser.parse_args().date
```

I am missing something in this code. Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want it so that if the current day is either Saturday or Sunday, then the entered date that is passed as a command line argument should be **date - 1 day** or **date - 2 days.**

So, if today's date is passed (11/23/2022) on Monday-Friday it'll return the date as is but if the same date is passed on Saturday, it'll return 11/22/2022.

To do the operation of subtracting days from the current day you'll need to [use time delta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441152/20473839).

This is my solution based of my assumptions of what you are asking

```
import argparse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('date')
passed_in_date = parser.parse_args().date

tdate = datetime.strptime(passed_in_date, "%m/%d/%Y")


weekno = datetime.today().weekday()
print(f"weekno of today is: {weekno}")
if weekno==5:
    tdate = tdate - timedelta(days=1)
elif weekno==6:
    tdate = tdate - timedelta(days=2)


print(tdate.date())
```

##### OutPut

```
#running on a Wednesday (for example) date returns same as passed
python .\date.py 11/26/2022
weekno of today is: 2
2022-11-26

#example for testing if running on a sunday
python .\date.py 11/23/2022
weekno of today is: 6
2022-11-21
```

If you wanted to see the date change just manually set weekno to 5 or 6 for testing.