# Python datetime.time and arithmetic operations

Tags: python, datetime

How to get sum and difference of two `datetime.time` variables in Python? For example:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
act_time = datetime.time(now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
diff = act_time - finish_time
```

Comment: What do you mean by sum?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just difference of two times?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685201/how-to-add-hours-to-current-time-in-python/13685221#13685221

Comment: @hafron this solution should fit to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/51042/461493

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm searching for, maybe it doesn't help my code to be simple and clear but it works. Thank you @tony

Comment: It's easier to get a `datetime.time` instance from a `datetime.datetime` instance by calling the latter's `.time()` method.

Answer (score 14):

Try this for difference:

```
#----------------------------- 
# Dates produce timedeltas when subtracted.

diff = date2 - date1
diff = datetime.date(year1, month1, day1) - datetime.date(year2, month2, day2)
#----------------------------- 

bree = datetime.datetime(1981, 6, 16, 4, 35, 25)
nat  = datetime.datetime(1973, 1, 18, 3, 45, 50)

difference = bree - nat
print "There were", difference, "minutes between Nat and Bree"
#=> There were 3071 days, 0:49:35 between Nat and Bree

weeks, days = divmod(difference.days, 7)

minutes, seconds = divmod(difference.seconds, 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)

print "%d weeks, %d days, %d:%d:%d" % (weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds)
#=> 438 weeks, 5 days, 0:49:35

#----------------------------- 
print "There were", difference.days, "days between Bree and Nat." 
#=> There were 3071 days between bree and nat
```

Operations:

```
#----------------------------- 
# Adding to or Subtracting from a Date
# Use the rather nice datetime.timedelta objects

now = datetime.date(2003, 8, 6)
difference1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
difference2 = datetime.timedelta(weeks=-2)

print "One day in the future is:", now + difference1
#=> One day in the future is: 2003-08-07

print "Two weeks in the past is:", now + difference2
#=> Two weeks in the past is: 2003-07-23

print datetime.date(2003, 8, 6) - datetime.date(2000, 8, 6)
#=> 1095 days, 0:00:00

#----------------------------- 
birthtime = datetime.datetime(1973, 01, 18, 3, 45, 50)   # 1973-01-18 03:45:50

interval = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5, minutes=17, hours=2, days=55) 
then = birthtime + interval

print "Then is", then.ctime()
#=> Then is Wed Mar 14 06:02:55 1973

print "Then is", then.strftime("%A %B %d %I:%M:%S %p %Y")
#=> Then is Wednesday March 14 06:02:55 AM 1973

#-----------------------------
when = datetime.datetime(1973, 1, 18) + datetime.timedelta(days=55) 
print "Nat was 55 days old on:", when.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").lstrip("0")
#=> Nat was 55 days old on: 3/14/1973

#----------------------------- 
# Adding to or Subtracting from a Date
# Use the rather nice datetime.timedelta objects

now = datetime.date(2003, 8, 6)
difference1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
difference2 = datetime.timedelta(weeks=-2)

print "One day in the future is:", now + difference1
#=> One day in the future is: 2003-08-07

print "Two weeks in the past is:", now + difference2
#=> Two weeks in the past is: 2003-07-23

print datetime.date(2003, 8, 6) - datetime.date(2000, 8, 6)
#=> 1095 days, 0:00:00

#----------------------------- 
birthtime = datetime.datetime(1973, 01, 18, 3, 45, 50)   # 1973-01-18 03:45:50

interval = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5, minutes=17, hours=2, days=55) 
then = birthtime + interval

print "Then is", then.ctime()
#=> Then is Wed Mar 14 06:02:55 1973

print "Then is", then.strftime("%A %B %d %I:%M:%S %p %Y")
#=> Then is Wednesday March 14 06:02:55 AM 1973

#-----------------------------
when = datetime.datetime(1973, 1, 18) + datetime.timedelta(days=55) 
print "Nat was 55 days old on:", when.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").lstrip("0")
#=> Nat was 55 days old on: 3/14/1973
```

Source: http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html

Comment: information overflow.